# Maven upload generated documentation/json file to repository

Tags: java, maven, repository

I use a private MavenPlugin to automatically generate a documentation for my web / rest service. This plugin generates a huge JSON file that I would like to upload along with my jar files to the repository so that you don't have to checkout the project and execute the maven goal again to get the documentation. I have to share the documentation of a specific version on request so I thought I store them along with the versions/artifacts in the repository (Either as file or as archive containng only this one file).

I have considered three possibilities yet:

- Create a new Maven plugin that does this kind of uploads for me, which has to deal with detecting the repos it should push the json to (local and remote + config).
- Use some kind of assembly plugin configuration/resource plugin to include the documentation in either the artifact.jar or source.jar. But IMO it should not be in there since its big and a you can create it with the sources yourself and b i don't want to download and extract it from the artifact.jar.
- Edit the MavenPlugin to tell the install/deploy plugin to include that json file and upload it to my repos. If possible without specifying explicit config for the install/deploy plugin in the pom that uses the MavenPlugin.

Number three is my preferred one, but I have no clue how to achieve it. (I will probably debug the source or javadoc plugin to check how they do it, if I don't find a good solution here)
Number two is an option I would use if there is no better alternative.
Number one seems quite awkward and sound like much work I would like to avoid.^^

Any ideas how i could implement option 3 or any other alternatives I might have missed?

Please Java or pom.xml only. No ant, no grails/gradle, no bash/shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [assembly plugin's](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) `single` goal to package the files into a separate classified jar (e.g. `myApp-jsondocs.jar`). The resulting assembly will be attached to the project by default - see the `attach` parameter of the goal for more information.

Comment: This was a good starting point.
With that I found the following sources, that will help me to integrate this in the plugin.
[maven-assembly-plugin - AbstractAssemblyMojo](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-assembly-plugin-2.6/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/assembly/mojos/AbstractAssemblyMojo.java?view=markup)
which references:
[MavenProjectHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven/maven-project/2.2.1/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProjectHelper.java/#29) which does exactly what i need,